# renderd items coming through event bus -Vue js

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a data page</h1>
    <p v-for="data in dummyData" :key="data.id">{{ data.title }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from '../main'

export default {
  name: "Data",
  data() {
    return {
      dummyData: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "Dummy Data One",
          completed: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Dummy Data Two",
          completed: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Dummy Data Three",
          completed: false
        },
      ]
    }
  },

  created() {
    eventBus.$on('pass-todo', (**obj**) => {
      var parsedobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
      console.log(parsedobj)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I pass the object that is coming from another component through evenBus to the template so I can render it ?? More specific I actually want to add that coming object to the dummyData and rendered it anyway!!

Comment: I won't ask why you're not using a prop :/ remove the **'s wrapping obj, then do `this.dummyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: I have to use only one component to view dummyData and the other components data (array of objects that is already I have fetched in here)as well in a page. Getting it here in created  but not able to pass it in template to render.

Comment: Okay. I have removed ** and its working. I have console out. Now how can I pass the dummyData to the template for rendering?

Comment: re-read my comment above, the part at the end will solve it.. be aware of :key if your sending in arrays with the same id's as it won't re-render if they don't change

Comment: also heads up that eventBus is going away in Vue3: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html#overview I strongly suggest to organize your components better so you can pass this as a prop

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys. Got a lot info here. Thats amazing community. This was my first question in stack overflow.